# Autofac Resolution in Static Method

Tags: extension-methods, autofac, static-methods

Looking for an answer (or an alternative) to this.

I'm refactoring one of our core applications to use some DI.  The weapon of choice is Autofac.

Everything has been going swell until I stumbled upon this extension method:

```
 public static bool ActionAuthorized(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName)
    {


        IRouteService _routeService; //<---------How do I get the instance here?


        Models.Routing.Routes thisRoute = _routeService.GetRoutes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Action == actionName && x.Controller == controllerName);

        ///removed for brevity....

        return false;
    }
```

This extension is used to secure parts of the application (show the link, hide the link , etc).

Fortunately the extension is used in only one View (_shared) - but it is a layout view - so it hits everything.

I was contemplating refactoring the signature to inject the `List<Routes>` like this:

```
 public static bool ActionAuthorized(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, List<Routes> routes)
```

That would make this simple:

```
Models.Routing.Routes thisRoute = routes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Action == actionName && x.Controller == controllerName);
```

But like I said this is a partial (_shared) view.

I would need to modify EVERY ViewModel to include Routes in the signature...which I really do not want to do.

The fundamental problem is DI and Static Classes is bad ju ju....I get it.  However Extension methods are part of (and a powerful feature to) .NET development.  It is not far fetched to assume that a Business Logic component (service) would be needed inside custom extension methods.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're stuck with a static, the answer is "service location." It's not pretty, but it is what it is.

It looks like you're using MVC, which would mean using  `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService()`.

Comment: This turned into something much bigger with a lot of technical debates between my developers.  It is comical how this unearthed a larger convention we have been using.  But I thank @Travis for the answer.  I was able to use it elsewhere.